# Javascript Checkbox From a Table Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the following code the alert comes back as 'undefined' when I would like is to return True or False depending on if the checkbox is check at the time that the user triggers the JavaScript to run.

The user is triggering it with a button. Currently when the user presses the button the script returns a 'undefined' for each row of the table.

Eventually I would like to create a JavaScript array that I will pass back to the server with an Ajax call but this is of little use if I can cannot determine the state of the check boxes for every row of the table.

Also, I'm using Jinja2 templating which explains the curly brackets but this should be of little consequence because the table is being created without issue when the HTML renders.

```
var table = document.getElementById("filterTable");
for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
    var isChecked = (table.rows[i].cells[2].checked);
    alert(isChecked);
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table hover" id = "filterTable">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Active</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for dep in dependencies %}
        <tr class="row">
            <td><p>{{dep.origin}}</p></td>
            <td><p>{{dep.destination}}</p></td>
            <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="isSelected"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is the first child of `td` not the `td`  itself (`cells[2]` returns third `td`) so `checked` property of `td` element would be always `undefined`.

You can get the checkbox from [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property.

```
var isChecked = table.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].checked;
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById("filterTable");
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  var isChecked = (table.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].checked);
  alert(isChecked);
}
```

```html
<table id="filterTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Origin</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <p>{{dep.origin}}</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>{{dep.destination}}</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="isSelected" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

In case there are other elements as the child then you can get it using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method with [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var isChecked = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked;
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById("filterTable");
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  var isChecked = (table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked);
  alert(isChecked);
}
```

```html
<table id="filterTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Origin</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <p>{{dep.origin}}</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>{{dep.destination}}</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="isSelected" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`table.rows[i].cells[2]` only find the `td` that contains the `checkbox`.

You need to query for the `checkbox` before you check the property.

```
var td = table.rows[i].cells[2];
var checkbox = td..querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
```